# How to upload datetime string into "TIME" field bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

I'm trying to upload a bunch of data into Bigquery, and the column that fail is "TIME" type.

I'm tried to insert a datetime to that field with the following values:

- "2020-03-23T00:00:00"
- "2020-03-23 00:00:00"
- "2020-03-23 00:00:00 UTC"

But with the three options, Bigquery job return the following answer:

`{'reason': 'invalidQuery', 'location': 'query', 'message': 'Invalid time string "2020-03-23T00:00:00" Field: time; Value: 2020-03-23T00:00:00'}`

How can I upload a datetime string into `TIME` column into BigQuery?

I'm using apache Airflow to upload data from a DAG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of those strings are a `TIME`. All of those strings are a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`.

To solve this problem without changing the underlying source data, make sure to load this data into a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` column (instead of `TIME`).

Comment: Correct answer, but what should I insert to correspond to the ```TIME``` type?

Comment: a time! like "20:35:15"

Comment: More information available here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#time_type